# Creating a floating table to join to in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

In a database I'm missing a few basic tables that should provide the reference to a Type; these were hard-coded in the software. In order not to endlessly write `case` statements to change these values, I want to copy paste a simple floating table each time I need this data.

I'm completely new to the `declare` type statements, and so far no luck in creating a subquery I can paste into my scripts. The result should be like so:

```
| Type ID |   Period |
----------------------
|      1  |      day |
|      2  |     week |
|      3  |    month |
|      4  |  quarter |
|      5  |     year |
```

I simply want to declare this table as a subquery so I can `join` it on other tables containing `type ID's`

Comment: Sounds like what you actually want to a "lookup table" and then you would `JOIN` to that table instead; the problem has nothing to do with `DECLARE` (which is mainly used to create variables).

Comment: Either create tables or views to store these values and then just join to them. What you should NOT do is code this in every query or script that needs these values. Why? Because they will inevitably change at some point and you DON'T want to correct every script that you wrote.

Comment: @Larnu I figured I was on the wrong track with this declare thing. How would a lookup table work though?

Comment: @SMor That would be my normal go-to solution but I have no rights to create views or tables in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary table is probably the simplest method because you can do this in one step:

```
select 1 as type_id, 'day' as period
into #temp_type_period union all
select 2 as type_id, 'week' union all
select 3 as type_id, 'month' union all
select 4 as type_id, 'quarter' union all
select 5 as type_id, 'year' ;
```

Using `declare`, you have to declare the table and then insert into it:

```
declare @type_period table (
    type_id int,
    period varchar(255)
);

insert into @type_period (type_id, period)
    select 1 as type_id, 'day' as period
    select 2 as type_id, 'week' union all
    select 3 as type_id, 'month' union all
    select 4 as type_id, 'quarter' union all
    select 5 as type_id, 'year' ;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works just fine. Hypothetically; at what point would a long list of unions become a performance issue?

Comment: @Sambo . . . The `union all`s are going to be a minimal performance issue.  I mean, you could use a `values()` clause as well, but I think the performance would be the same.  The performance issue would be on using the table; you can add a primary key or index to speed that up.